# Terence Tao Volume 1 pigeonhole principle

Tags: real-analysis, pigeonhole-principle

I am self-studying Terence Tao Volume 1. I am having few issues. I don't understand the question about pigeonhole principle below.
[image]

Comment: Well, part of your problem might be that part of the text is cut off.

Comment: Do you know how to fill this question up ? I would like to attempt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the question:

[image]

Do you also need help with the proof?

Comment: I will attempt it first. Thank you so much!

Comment: Isn't this proven by the fact that $\# (\cup A_i) \leq \Sigma \#A_i$

Comment: @joeblacksmith precisely, $n<\#(\bigcup_i A_i) \leqslant \sum_i \# A_i$.

Comment: Okay perfect thanks so much.